# Is there a way to create rules, actions, message schemas programatically in IBM Watson IoT platform?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot

Is there a way to create rules, actions, message schemas from a program using REST APIs?
I want a simple rule to be configured like `eventData.temperature > 50 C` do some action. Can this be done programatically?

Also, Can this value `50 C` be configured somewhere instead of hard-coding in the rule?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create the rules so they appear in the real-time dashboard in Watson?  If not, you should be able to create an application with logic.  Have you tried the Node-RED sample that comes with boilerplate, it has logic similar to what you mention and you can customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Before RealTime Insights was merged into iot platform we had a specific API to manage rules and actions. Since the merge was applied, it seems that the RTI API is not available anymore.